# Checking whether a state is almost orthogonal to permutation invariant states

Tags: quantum-state, information-theory, linear-algebra

Let us consider
\begin{equation}
|T\rangle = |\psi \rangle^{\otimes m}
\end{equation}
for an $n$-qubit quantum state $|\psi\rangle$. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the space of all $(m + 1)$-partite states that are invariant under permutations. Consider $|\psi\rangle|T\rangle$, which belongs to the space $\mathcal{V}$. I am trying to prove:

1. For $|\phi\rangle$ orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$, $|\phi\rangle |T\rangle$ is almost orthogonal to $\mathcal{V}$, upto an error $\mathcal{O}\big(\frac{1}{m}\big)$.
2. There exists a measurement to determine whether $|\phi\rangle |T\rangle$ is in $\mathcal{V}$, upto an error $\mathcal{O}\big(\frac{1}{m}\big)$, and when doing so, the state $|T\rangle$ is only disturbed by $\mathcal{O}\big(\frac{1}{m}\big)$.

(For reference, these statements are in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.6898.pdf) paper, in the last paragraph of page 13).

Comment: Take a look at page 41 in the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the projector onto the symmetric subspace. We want to find
$$
\max|\langle\gamma|\phi,T\rangle|
$$
for $|\gamma\rangle\in \mathcal{V}$. This is equivalent to
$$
\max|\langle\gamma|P|\phi,T\rangle|,
$$
so if we calculate $P|\phi\rangle|T\rangle$, then $|\gamma\rangle$ will be the normalised state parallel to that.

Now, if we project $|\phi\rangle|T\rangle$ onto the fully symmetric subspace, we get
$$
|\gamma\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}|\psi\rangle^{\otimes (i-1)}|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle^{\otimes(m+1-i)}.
$$
Hence, the maximum value of the overlap is $1/\sqrt{m+1}$. If you're talking about an error, you'r probably talking about a measurement, and hence need the mod-square, so the probability of finding the state in the symmetric subspace is $1/(m+1)$.

How to perform the measurement? I could just specify measurement projectors $\{P,I-P\}$. However, you may subsequently ask how you perform that measurement using standard gate elements. I've never looked at this in great detail, but assume it is related to topics such as [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407082). Equally, for this specific form of state, I imagine you could do something generalising the swap-test (which projects two systems onto their symmetric subspace).

---

Further explanation of the claimed result:

Let
$$
|\omega_j\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\omega^{kj}|\psi\rangle^{\otimes (k-1)}|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle^{\otimes(m+1-k)}
$$
where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/(m+1)}$. Each of the $|\omega_j\rangle$ is an eigenvector, eigenvalue $\omega^j$, of the cyclic permutation operator. The cyclic permutation operator and the projector onto the symmetric subspace commute (because the symmetric subspace is invariant under permutations), and hence they share a common eigenbasis and, in particular, *only* $|\omega_0\rangle$ is in the symmetric subspace.

We have
$$
|\phi\rangle|T\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}\sum_{j=0}^m|\omega_j\rangle.
$$
Thus,
$$
P|\phi\rangle|T\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}|\omega_0\rangle.
$$
The normalised version of this is hence
$$
|\gamma\rangle=|\omega_0\rangle.
$$

Comment: Could you comment on why the projection of $\vert\phi\rangle\vert T\rangle$ gives the state you got? And why it is also denoted as $\vert\gamma\rangle$?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you get started, If two vectors are orthogonal, then their inner product is zero. The inner product is a measure of how similar two vectors are; or, the degree to which the first vector lies along the second. So you know that |⟩|⟩~ 0